# How to get uniform spacing between paragraphs across several pages?

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, page-breaking, tcolorbox

I am using `\flushbottom` to get pages of equal height. When I now insert a `tcolorbox` which is set to be unbreakable such that a page break becomes necessary, only the spaces between paragraphs on the page right before it (third page in the figure) are stretched, while on all pages before the spacing between paragraphs is normal:
[image]

I would like to have all spaces between paragraphs on all pages before equally stretched, so that the spacing between paragraphs is uniform across all pages, like this:
[image]

Here is my MWE, which contains the examples shown in the figures:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\paragraph{In this example, we see small gaps between paragraphs on the first two pages and large ones on the third page:}

\lipsum[1-4]
\begin{tcolorbox}
\lipsum[2]
\end{tcolorbox}
\lipsum[1-6]

\begin{tcolorbox}
{}
\lipsum[4]
\end{tcolorbox}
\pagebreak
\setlength{\parskip}{0.5cm plus 0.125cm}
\paragraph{I prefer to have the gaps between paragraphs uniform like this:}
\lipsum[1-4]
\begin{tcolorbox}
\lipsum[2]
\end{tcolorbox}
\lipsum[1-6]

\begin{tcolorbox}
{}
\lipsum[4]
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible because TeX can't go back to earlier pages: once a page is shipped out, it's gone. At least, I don't think you can do it without something which changes that output routine. Or maybe you could do something over multiple compilations....?

Answer (score 2):

Should be easy: Put `\raggedbottom` just before `\begin{document}`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\raggedbottom

\begin{document}
\paragraph{In this example, we see small gaps between paragraphs on the first two pages and large ones on the third page:}

\lipsum[1-4]
\begin{tcolorbox}
\lipsum[2]
\end{tcolorbox}
\lipsum[1-6]

\begin{tcolorbox}
{}
\lipsum[4]
\end{tcolorbox}
\pagebreak
\setlength{\parskip}{0.5cm plus 0.125cm}
\paragraph{I prefer to have the gaps between paragraphs uniform like this:}
\lipsum[1-4]
\begin{tcolorbox}
\lipsum[2]
\end{tcolorbox}
\lipsum[1-6]

\begin{tcolorbox}
{}
\lipsum[4]
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please read the first sentence of my question: "I am using `\flushbottom` to get pages of equal height." Using `\raggedbottom` does generally not result in pages of equal height.

Comment: Well, there's no `\flushbottom` in your MWE. So, in that case it is impossible, as cfr pointed out in his comment above, because you cannot have large unbreakable boxes and expect every page to be the same height. It wouldn't even work, if TeX could go back to already shipped out pages. It is like stacking wodden boxes of different sizes on top of each other and requiring each stack to be of equal height.

Comment: The `\flushbottom` is automatically set by the book class in my MWE. As my second example shows, it is possible to get the desired result, the question is only whether it can be done automatically. Since cfr suggests doing something over multiple compilations, there is still some hope.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I thought you meant manually. I can't imagine how this should be accomplished even using multiple compilations. If you think about `figure` and `table`, these are put at more or less random positions in the document to get an (almost) flushed bottom. But if you want everything in place, I don't think you can do that without rearranging the boxes in the document flow. You could try to put the gray boxes in `figure` environments and use  the `float` package with option `H`.

Comment: @alexraasch The `book` class, in the default `twoside` mode, uses `\flushbottom`. However, it's not possible to get uniform spacing unless one resorts to `\raggedbottom` or adds stretch to `\baselineskip`.

Comment: @egreg -- it has to be handled manually, but `\looseness` can adjust the length of (some) paragraphs for a final "polishing".  (probably used in earnest only by people like knuth and jean-juc doumont.)