# Different vertical spacing between paragraphs

Tags: spacing

I sometimes get annoying weird spaces in my latex and I dont know how to fix them. these are my global variables. I cannot paste my code unless someone tells me how I can convert all text into random characters. Using this template https://www2.securecms.com/ICIP2017/Papers/PaperKit.html#Templates

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{spconf,amsmath,graphicx}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}
```

the texts that give error. I am not using any functions or local variables. They are all texts.

```
Many lines of text. LIDAR sensors that provide a 3D map of the environment around the vehicle are unequivocally more powerful than a single stereo-pair.

Despite these attractive features, the use of LIDAR sensors are still...

\begin{figure}[t]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{res}\\
    \caption{The workflow of our object proposal algorithm.}
    \label{fig:workflow}
\end{figure}

Many lines of text. Here, we briefly review works that will be used as a baseline for comparison.

In the Selective Search (SS) algorithm \cite{selectivesearch}, pixels analyzed
```

[image]

Comment: is the space you're referring to the different space between paragraphs?  what you've shown isn't enough to say for sure, but often this is caused by the presence of something that takes a space that is not an integral number of baselines, such as a display (doesn't look like you have any) or a section heading.  since the partial page on the left doesn't have the baselines aligned with the page on the right, my guess is that there's a heading at the top.  maybe this helps: [How to get uniform spacing between paragraphs across several pages?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/298640/579)

Comment: Yes the spacing between the paragraphs contained by the red boxes are not similar. I do have a figure placed at the top right of that page but the code containing the image is place above "The last few years ...." so I am not sure how it could affect the spacing of the paragraph after it. I will still read the post you linked.

Comment: well, it;s the presence of the float that's causing the different alignment.  what you're looking for is a "grid" approach.  look for other questions here that ask about that.  making specific adjustments depends on the document class and packages you're using, which you haven't specified.

Comment: okay I will browse through the internet. I am using a default template from the website I posted. I believe I only added tabu, subfig, and color as additional global variables. I have posted the code for my figure. All my global variables are there as it is in the original post. I have to go to sleep now

Comment: BTW Sometimes that difference is just caused by TeX trying to put some more text onto one page (keywords `\raggedbottom`/`\flushbottom`).

Comment: Wow the \raggedbottom works really well. Thanks !

Comment: @user124577 - Please post your comment as an answer, so that the present query may be treated as 'answered'.

Comment: @Mico I'll do in the next half hour.

Answer (score 2):

LaTeX treats text on a page very differently according to its spacing options. Some classes want LaTeX to fill out the white space on a page best possible, others want it to just keep the text where it is.

The two main options are:

- `\flushbottom`: in-/decreases text spacing as needed to fill page,
- `\raggedbottom`: there is no "correction" of text spacing

You will need option `\raggedbottom` to ensure that paragraph spacing is equal at all points (and on all pages).